# Jolt Transform - How to transform a value null a string "null"

Tags: json, transform, jolt

How to transform a value **`null`** a string **`"null"`**

Input

```json
{
  "sellerOrderId": null,
  "origin": "Fulfillment",
  "merchantName": null
}
```

Output

```json
{
  "sellerOrderId": "null",
  "origin": "Fulfillment",
  "merchantName": "null"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply **toString** function within a **modify** transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": ["=toString", "null"]
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your orientation solved my problem!